# Angular 2 doesn't set Content-Type to 'multipart/form-data' but to 'application/json'

Tags: angular, upload, ionic2, multipartform-data, multipart

I'm trying to upload files in a Ionic mobile project based on Angular 2.

I have a FormData object with at least 3 fields (_id, type and files).

```
this.formData = new FormData();
if (fileCount > 0) { // a file was selected
  for (let i = 0; i < fileCount; i++) {
    this.formData.append('file', inputEl.files.item(i));
  }
}

[... in the upload method I pass this.formData as files ...]

files.append('_id', data._id);
files.append('tipo', tipo);
```

I pass it to my upload method and I set the "Content-Type" to 'multipart/form-data'

```
let options: RequestOptionsArgs = new RequestOptions();
options.headers = this.headers; (In this.headers I have my Authorization header set)
options.headers.delete('Content-Type');
options.headers.set('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
```

I make an http post

```
this.http.post(
  `${this.apiUrl}/utenti/upload`,
  files,
  options
)
```

but I receive a bad response from the server:

```
Sorry, an error occurred loading the page (500)
Unexpected token -
```

I look into Chrome's Network tab and I can see that my Request headers are wrong:

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

On the other hand my payload is correct with a form-data style:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryKiWq1WTTF3AJCFRX
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="IMG_0001.JPG"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


------WebKitFormBoundaryKiWq1WTTF3AJCFRX
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="_id"

58e7b968bed0575e13efc63c
------WebKitFormBoundaryKiWq1WTTF3AJCFRX
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="tipo"

foto
------WebKitFormBoundaryKiWq1WTTF3AJCFRX--
```

Any guess on what's wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

If you have implemented an interceptor, check that you aren't overriding the headers.